# UILabel in segue.destination - Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I've got a ViewController class, and two IBOutlet UILablels that I created from storyboard.

Here is the code of the class:

```
import UIKit

class AnnouncementViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var infoTV: UITextView!
    var mail: String = ""
    var url: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    
    func set(_ announcement: [String: String]) {
        
        print(announcement)
        
        nameLabel.text = announcement["name"]    // here goes the error
        self.infoTV.text = announcement["info"]
        self.mail = announcement["email"]!
        self.url = announcement["url"]!
        
    }
    
}
```

And here is the code from another class (TableViewController) I've got:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        guard segue.identifier == "announcementSegue" else { return }
        
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let announcement = tasks[indexPath.row]
        
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! AnnouncementViewController
        
        destinationVC.set(announcement)
        
}
```

The error I get is:
`Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

So, `nameLabel` is `nil`. I cannot get why it is.

Comment: > Tip : Think of a model struct/class instead of using a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1** call `loadViewIfNeeded()`

```
let destinationVC = segue.destination as! AnnouncementViewController
destinationVC.view.loadViewIfNeeded()
destinationVC.set(announcement)
```

**Solution 2**

```
let destinationVC = segue.destination as! AnnouncementViewController 
destinationVC.ann = announcement
```

---

```
var ann = [String: String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    set(ann)
}

func set(_ announcement: [String: String]) { 
    print(announcement)
    
    nameLabel.text = announcement["name"]    // no error
    self.infoTV.text = announcement["info"]
    self.mail = announcement["email"]!
    self.url = announcement["url"]!
    
}
```

Comment: view may doesn't exist in viewDidLoad,
call set(ann) in viewWillAppears

Comment: @ВладимирКовальчук it does exist inside viewDidLoad

Comment: Thank you, I used solution 2, it works now :)